# Finding out wether a Radio Button was Selected in a Radio Button-Group

Tags: javascript, xml, button, radio-button, sapui5

i work with SapUi5 and i want to know a faster way to check wether/how many buttons where clicked in a Radio Button Group.

Situation: In the Section there are 3 - **RadioGroups** with 4 Options pro Group, i.e. 12 in Total, i have given each Group an ID.

Now in a specific File: the Operation sap.ui.getCore("idOfRadioButtonGroup").getSelected() - does Work and gives out wether a Button was clicked, however in the File that i operate from this Operation seems to now work.

There is another possiblity to check wether a button was clicked in one of this 3 Groups:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("idFirstRadioGroup").mAggregations.buttons[0-3].mProperties.selected 
//(4 Buttons pro Group)
```

However i would like to know a different solution

Expected Results: A possibility to find out if a button from a Radio Group

was clicked. (1 Button/4 can be clicked pro RadioGroup)

Actual Results: Doesn't seem to work to full extend

Comment: What do you mean with "in the File that i operate from"? In which case it does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the function "[getSelectedButton](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.RadioButtonGroup/methods/getSelectedButton)".

> Returns the selected radio button.